# Can C3PO connect to another url if current database unavailable?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, c3p0, failover

We use C3PO in our application. 
it connected to `database_1`.

Sometimes this connection can be broken. At this case we should reconnect to another database (`database_2`)(mirror database). Ideally I want to have a list of reserved databases in configuration.

Does `C3PO` allow this ?

Maybe `sql-server` jdbc driver allow something like this ?

Comment: This can be done within the URL depending on your database servers.  What database are you using?

Comment: @DMoses I use ms sql

Comment: unless it can be done as @DMoses suggests within the JDBC URL, c3p0 doesn't support fallback databases, alas. it might, someday, but it doesn't now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C3P0 does not support failover.  JTDS jdbc drivers do not support failover to my knowledge.  MSSQL drivers support failover https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988(v=sql.110).aspx  (see failoverPartner in the JDBC url)

I could give you more information if it was Oracle, you'll need to look at microsoft documentation on failover to see if it fits your needs.